# two different colored violin plots on the same graph

Tags: plotly, violin-plot

I am using the following command to create a violin plot:

```
    fig = FF.create_violin(data, data_header='Number', group_header='Group', height=500, width=800, title= "Number of Videos Watched",colors='YlOrRd')
    py.iplot(fig, filename= "Number of Videos Watched")
```

I want to use two colors of my choice. I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Can someone tell me how to do it?
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky but this [example](https://plot.ly/python/violin-plot/#multiple-violins) gives a good starting point. The data for the two plots is stored in a Pandas `dataframe`.

First lets create a list of random values

```
y = numpy.random.randn(Nr)
```

and random selections from those numbers

```
gr = numpy.random.choice(list(violins), Nr)
```

then the numbers are modified, each selection differently.

```
for i, letter in enumerate(violins):
    y[gr == letter] *= norm_params[i][1] + norm_params[i][0]
```

and assigned to a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Score = y, Group = gr))
```

and finally the DataFrame is plotted

```
fig = plotly.tools.FigureFactory.create_violin(df, data_header='Score', group_header='Group', colors='YlOrRd')
```

If you replace the data with your own values, e.g. `values1` and `values2`

```
#get the groups
gr = ['Value1' for i in range(Nr)]
gr.extend(['Value2' for i in range(Nr)])

#assign the values
y = numpy.random.randn(2*Nr)
y[0:Nr] = values1
y[Nr:] = values2
```

you could get your own violin plots.

---

Here is a minimal example which creates two violin plots.

[image]

```
import plotly
import numpy
import pandas as pd
plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()
Nr = 250
violins = 'AB'
y = numpy.random.randn(Nr)
gr = numpy.random.choice(list(violins), Nr)
norm_params = [(0, 1.2), (0.7, 1)]

for i, letter in enumerate(violins):
    y[gr == letter] *= norm_params[i][1] + norm_params[i][0]
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Score = y, Group = gr))

data_header = 'Score'
group_header = 'Group'

fig = plotly.tools.FigureFactory.create_violin(df, data_header='Score', group_header='Group', colors='YlOrRd')

plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename='Two Violin Plots')
```